# ECHO Results into a FORM after multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql, forms, search, edit

I've seen tutorials on doing this sort of things echo'ing the results directly from the form into a different form on the following page however the issue I'm facing is slightly different and I can't find any threads that cover it, I'm sure someone will prove how much of a novice I am by answering this however.

I have a search form as shown here:

```
<!DOCTYPE  HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"          "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
 <html> 
  <head> 
    <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1"> 
    <title>Search  Contacts</title> 
  </head> 
  <p><body> 
    <h3>Search  Contacts Details</h3> 
    <p>You  may search either by first or last name</p> 
    <form  method="post" action="search.php?go"  id="client"> 
      <input  type="text" name="name"> 
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html> 
</p>
```

The results are then display in a table on the Search.PHP page, the code is shown here:
`enter code here`

```
  } 
 }
}  
?>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Client/title>
 <link href="/csstwo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
<div id="Header">
<h1>Search results</h1>
<div id="Banner"></div>
<div id="logo"></div>
<div style="clear:  both;"></div>
</div> <!-- /Header -->

<body>
    <div id="nav">
    <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>   
            <li><a href="">Client</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="client.php">Add a Client</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Client</a></li>
                    </li><li><a href="#">Client List</a></li>
                </ul>   
            <li><a href="">Case</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="case.php">Add a Case</a></li>
                    </li><li><a href="caselist.php">Manage Case</a></li>
                </ul>   
            <li><a href=#">Help <img src="arrow.jpg"></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Case</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Client</a></li>
                    </li><li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
<div id="content">  

  <table width="70%" cellpadding="5" cellspace="5" position="centre">
<tr>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Forename</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Surname</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Postcode</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address Line One</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address Line Two</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Town/City</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Contact Number</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Manage Client</strong></td>
</tr>
 <?php while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $ID =$row ['ClientID'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $FirstName =$row ['forename'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $LastName =$row ['surname'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['postcode'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['addresslineone'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['addresslinetwo'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['towncity'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row ['contactnumber'] ?></td>
        <td><a href='manageclient.php?id={$row['id']}'>Manage</a></td>
    </tr>
  <?php } ?>
  </table>
  </body>
```

I have a link at the end that takes you to Manageclient.php, the user would select *Manage Client* on the Search.php page that displays results. This would then take the user to Manageclient.php with a prepopulate form from the results of Search.php.

I'm probably being extremely stupid but I can't seem to carry the results from the Search.php and echo them into the form on Manageclient.php, I always keep getting errors saying the variables are not defined.

I hope this makes sense and any help on this would be appreciated greatly.

EDIT:

I'm posting to this form on manageclient.php:

```
<form action="manageclient.php" method="post" form id="client">
 <div class="label">
  <h1> Edit a Client
 <span>Please enter the case's details below.</span>
 </h1>
<div class="label">*ClientID:
    <div class="txtbox">
        <input name="ClientID" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your First Name." value="<?php echo $result ['ClientID']; ?>"/>
    </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="label">*Forename:
    <div class="txtbox">
        <input name="forename" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name." value="<?php echo $result ['forename']; ?>"/>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="label">*Surname:
    <div class="txtbox">
        <input name="surname" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY." value="<?php echo $result ['surname']; ?>"/>
</div>
</div>
```

I get the following error messages:

Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\manageclient.php on line 105

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\manageclient.php on line 105

**Notice**:  Undefined index: ClientID in **C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\manageclient.php** on line **75**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: forename in **C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\manageclient.php** on line **81**

**Notice**:  Undefined index: surname in **C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\manageclient.php** on line **86**

FURTHER EDIT: Showing PHP in search.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
if(isset($_GET['go'])){ 
  if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){ 
  $name=$_POST['name']; 
  //connect  to the database 
  $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error()); 
  //-select  the database to use 
  $mydb=mysql_select_db("acatestdb"); 
  //-query  the database table 
  $sql="SELECT  ClientID, forename, surname, dateofbirth, postcode, addresslineone, addresslinetwo, towncity, contactnumber FROM clienttbl WHERE surname LIKE '%" . $name .  "%' OR forename LIKE '%" . $name ."%'"; 
  //-run  the query against the mysql query function 
  $result=mysql_query($sql); 
  //-create  while loop and loop through result set 

  } 
}
```

}
   ?>

Comment: `variables are not defined.` so show us full error message please. it must include the **name**  of undefined variable

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to use `$_POST['name']` somewhere. Creating a MySQL connection before querying is something I believe is necessary. Not to mention the **full error message**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are you asking for.

Your style is very unclear same as code :-(

But check this line:

`<td><a href='manageclient.php?id={$row['id']}'>Manage</a></td>`

should be

`<td><a href="manageclient.php?id=<?=$row['id'] ?>&ClientID=<?=$row['ClientID'] ?>&forename="<?=urlencode($row ['forename']) ?>&surname="<?=urlencode($row['surname']) ?>">Manage</a></td>`

and in your manageclient.php you can try:

```
<div class="label">*ClientID:
    <div class="txtbox">
        <input name="ClientID" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your First Name." value="<?=(isset($_GET['ClientID']))?$_GET['ClientID']:'' ?>"/>
    </div>  
</div>
<br>
<div class="label">*Forename:
    <div class="txtbox">
        <input name="forename" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="Enter Your Last Name." value="<?=(isset($_GET['forename']))?$_GET['forename']:'' ?>"/>
</div>
</div>
    <div class="label">*Surname:
    <div class="txtbox">
        <input name="surname" type="text" id="txt" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY." value="<?=(isset($_GET['surname']))?$_GET['surname']:'' ?>"/>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're unsure about something, do you really think posting it as an answer is the correct way to ask for clarification?

Comment: We are getting somewhere, the ClientID is now being carried across into the Form on manageclient.php. However it seems it does not want to carry over the forename and surname into the form. I do get these errors: 
Notice: Undefined variable: result in C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\search.php on line 77

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\acaproject\search.php on line 77

Comment: so where did you instantiate the `$result` variable?

Comment: Apologies I just realized I missed that off the above. It is in Search.php. I have made further amendments above so you can now see this.

Comment: You write terrible code... try to change  condition here `if(preg_match("/^[  a-zA-Z]+/", $_POST['name'])){` to `if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name'])){`

Comment: Thank you for the compliment and also for the further advice. I'm getting the same error message, the ClientID is being carried forward into the Form but the forename and surname aren't.

Comment: that is impossible. update your code fragments in your post to check

Comment: by the way are you sure that you have `ClientID` field in your table? I have feeling like your field is titled just `id`

Comment: Yeah my table does include ClientID. The ClientID does appear in the URL when I do click manage but the forename and surname do not, I don't know if that means anything. I get the same error and the Forename and Surname fields are left blank. I guess this is going to take sometime to resolve, thank you for your patience and help, at least I know have a ClientID that pulls through!

Comment: @Alex eventually this is now working. I removed the " on the href line so it now looks like this: `<td><a href="manageclient.php?id=<?=$row['ClientID']?>&ClientID=<?=$row['ClientID'] ?>&forename=<?=urlencode($row ['forename']) ?>&surname=<?=urlencode($row['surname']) ?>">Manage</a></td>`

Comment: Just guessing, but are you including the search.php file in your form? `require('search.php');`?